# If my boat is sinking should I bale or bail the water out?

Tags: word-usage, homonyms

From various literary examples it appears that I should manually 'bail' out the water to keep afloat but the automated water removal system in my vessel is a 'baling pump'.

While there is [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/452924), I cannot find any evidence that the present tense verb of *'to bail'* is *'baling'*.

*'bale'* may be an olde English of *'bail'* but why would a factory keep producing *'baling pumps'*? (see [baling pump](https://www.google.ca/search?q=baling+pump)) ?

Comment: I'm confused. The post that you link to indicates that both spellings, "bail" and "bale", are used for the verb, so I would expect that "bailing pump" and "baling pump" would both be used. How do the "various literary examples" of "baling pump" contradict this? It doesn't seem to be that difficult to find examples of the spelling "bailing pump": e.g. [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bailing%20pump%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Comment: @Jeeped - perhaps you misread 'waste' as 'water'.  You can't bale a liquid.

Comment: @AmI,then there would be no such thing as 'waste water'? I would think that in a sinking boat one might consider the water in the boat as 'waste' to be disposed of.

Comment: @sumelic, should I have included a *circa* in my inquiry?

Comment: Yes, but 'waste water' is still a liquid.  Baling refers to tying, and you can't tie a liquid.

Comment: @AmI, But a pump can collect it, contain it and expel it. While not literally tied, perhaps metaphorically 'tied to a conclusion'.

Comment: Nope, a bale remains tied after it is *expelled*.

Comment: When I followed your link to "baling pump" I saw several hits for "bailing pump", "bilge pump" and so on together with several hits for baling machinery and baling wire. However there were no hits for "baling pump" as such. This doesn't surprise me as I would **bail** water from a boat but **bale** straw, paper and cardboard. As others have said the two verbs have different meanings.

Comment: You say that the pump in your boat is a ***baling*** *pump*. Please provide evidence of that. Don't link to a general Google search (which is never authoritative) but to an actual website that shows your pump and uses that spelling for its name. (Or to a website that shows *any* pump that uses that word to describe it.) What is the make and model of your pump?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an unsupported premise (i.e. that "baling pump" is a term used for pumps that bail liquid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verb that means scooping water out of a boat is usually spelled "bail". However, the alternative spelling "bale" is also used by some writers. The "bale" spelling may be more common in the UK (the OED says [bail is "Now often less correctly"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/14685) spelled [bale, who's etymology is an "erroneous spelling of bail"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/14859)). The second spelling is not listed in all dictionaries (e.g. [Merriam-Webster only has bail](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bail)), so always using "bail" may be a safer pick, especially in the American English.

While either spelling is likely to be understood given a nautical context, a specific person is not likely to mix them together. If you use the base spelling "bail", then you should use "bailing" as the gerund form. If you prefer "bale", you'd use "baling". You should not write "bail" and "baling" together.

There are other verbs spelled "bail" (get somebody out of jail) and "bale" (form into a bale or bundle). If you're searching for uses of the first verb (referring to boats), you may find a lot of uses of these other verbs, so you should be careful in interpreting your results. Your search for "Baling pump" for instance, seems to turn up a lot of references to hydraulic pumps involved in "baling" machines which are used to create bales of things like straw or cardboard, not to pump water overboard on a boat.

Comment: Great clarification - +1

Comment: ***Bail out*** - came to mind, explained by Wiki as "... a colloquial term for the provision of financial help to a corporation or country which otherwise would be on the brink of failure or bankruptcy. ***The term is maritime in origin and describes the act of removing water from a sinking vessel using a bucket***."

Comment: There are a few related verbs, mostly derived from the one's I listed. There's an obscure form of "bail" related to animal handling, and two forms that are almost exclusively written with "out", the first referring to rescue from financial difficulties and second meaning to jump out of an airplane. The OED thinks that the financial "bail out" form is more related to prison bail than nautical bail/bale, but it also gets spelled "bale out" sometimes, so the etymology is likely pretty confused. The dictionary even mentions the possibility that it might come from the "bundle" version of "bale".

Comment: We use "bale out" in the UK as an alternative to "bail out" but only, so far as I am aware, to mean jumping from a doomed aircraft or, as a metaphor, to abandon an enterprise which is in trouble (as in "the investors baled out of  the food factory following the environmental health report"). This is supported by the [Cambridge online dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bail-out) which does not mention any maritime use of "bale".

Answer (score 0):

[Bail](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bail) is the typical form, but bale is listed on Lexico as a variant.

The origin is described there as:

> Early 17th century from obsolete bail ‘bucket’, from French baille, based on Latin bajulus ‘carrier’.

Further supported by [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bail#etymonline_v_201)

> "to dip water out of," 1610s, from baile (n.) "small wooden bucket" (mid-14c.), from nautical Old French baille "bucket, pail," from Medieval Latin *baiula (aquae), literally "porter of water," from Latin baiulare "to bear a burden" (see bail (n.1)).