# In British English, is "bail" or "bale" more common?

Tags: british-english, orthography

In American English, let's say we have something like

*Dude, I want to leave this party. Let's* **bail.**

This holds up in various American dictionaries (with the exception of *to bale out* of an airplane, train, etc.).

However, I understand that the same usage of "bail" in British English — meaning "abandon a commitment, obligation, or activity"¹ — is frequently **bale**. So my question is: How common is the spelling of "Let's bale" in British English, as opposed to "Let's bail"?

My free Oxford resource isn't specific. Is it 10%, 90%, or nobody keeps track because they're both equally accepted?

¹[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bail#h47109063163840)

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bale) has: **bale³** VERB *British* variant spelling of [bail](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bail).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If my boat is sinking should I bale or bail the water out?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467078/if-my-boat-is-sinking-should-i-bale-or-bail-the-water-out)

Comment: I would suggest it doesn't answer the question, because this question asks specifically about relative usages.

Comment: Note that "bail" and "bale" mean two different things, with two different etymologies.

Comment: If you’re talking about bale, you might have written “Hay Dude”. (Not be confused with “Hey Jude” — time for me to bale out.)

Comment: I kind of wonder if "bale out" doesn't derive from the parachutes used in WWI.  These were so large that they were only useful to balloon pilots, and likely would have been described as "bales" (in the hay sense).

Answer (score 4):

*Bail out* appears to be more common than *bale out* in BrE, at the moment at least. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=bail+out%2Cbale+out&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbail+out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbale+out%3B%2Cc0&corpus=29&year_end=2019)

[image: Ngram of "bale out" and "bail out", BrE]

Up to about 1970, the sources Google uses for this data had *bale* as more favoured; perhaps the influence of American English became more effective around that time.

The comparatively huge increase in *bale out* in BrE sources during the Second World War would indicate that aircraft were baled out of; changing the plot to include *of* in the phrases searched yields a graph of very similar shape.

By comparison, American English shows a similar hump for *bail out* during WW2, but *bale out* has always been less popular. The scale is the same as the first chart: note how *bale* is still relatively popular in BrE even now. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=bail+out%2Cbale+out&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbail+out%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbale+out%3B%2Cc0&corpus=28&year_end=2019)

[image: Ngram of "bale out" and "bail out", AmE]

Just for good measure, the overall incidence of the phrase regardless of spelling has followed much the same profile in AmE and BrE over the years of Google's sources ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=bail+out+%2B+bale+out+%3A+eng_gb_2019%2C+bail+out+%2B+bale+out+%3A+eng_us_2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28bail+out+%2B+bale+out+%3A+eng_gb_2019%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28bail+out+%2B+bale+out+%3A+eng_us_2019%29%3B%2Cc0&corpus=28&year_end=2019)), so the first chart shows how BrE spellings have swapped from *bale* to *bail.*

[image: Comparison between corpora]

Comment: I understand that, when comparing US and UK English frequencies, Google N-Grams get their figures from books published in the US and UK respectively. In each case, are books published on one country, but written in the other, excluded or included?

Comment: I have no idea; that's not in [their information page](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info). However, books written in one country and then re-published in another will generally be edited for spelling (so that AmE readers don't have to encounter words like *colour*). Thus these graphs should reflect usage in a useful way for this answer.

Comment: Although it is not a scientific fact, it is my impression that US readers are more protected from traumatic or world-order-destroying transPondial spellings than UK ones.

Comment: The Guardian will happily write of the US Department of Defense, whereas that august body often writes about the UK "Ministry of Defense".

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing will protect Ngrams from the misprints of the Grauniad.

Comment: But the Guardian was right in my example, by spelling a foreign proper name in its native fashion, and the US DoD wrong, by not doing so.

Comment: As anyone who actually reads it will tell you, the _Grauniad_ trope is a tired one, some decades past its sell-by date.

Comment: I know the processes at the Guardian have improved. However, proper names are a different thing to simple verbs. The US DoD should be spelled *Defense*, and the UK MoD should be spelled *Defence* in American publications. But that's hardly going to affect *bail* and *bale,* which are not proper nouns.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve lived in England my whole life and would consider “bale” to be incorrect; it’s “bail”.

Comment: Is this an opinion you can back up? I am never sure which way to spell it, and Lexico says I am not wrong either way.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is, for the purposes of etymology, "bail" is preferred and "bale" is considered an error. There is a word "bale" but it has quite a different meaning.

*(It is worth noting that in *“The vessel was holed beneath the waterline and the crew **bailed** [out].”* It is not possible to say if the crew jumped over the side or they tried to remove the water.)*

The OED, in an entry that has not been as yet fully updated since 1895 gives:

> **bale, v.3**

> **Etymology: Erroneous spelling** of **bail v.4
>
> **To lade or throw water out of a boat or ship with buckets (formerly called bails) or other vessels. Const. to bale the water out, bale the boat (out). to bale up: to scoop up. See bail v.4**
>
> **1842   F. Marryat** Percival Keene I. xvi. 231   *Let's bale the boat out first.*

And

> **bail, v.4**
>
> **Etymology:** < bail n.5 **Now often less correctly bale v.3**   To lade or throw water out of a boat, etc., with buckets (formerly called
> bails), pails, basins, or other vessels.
> **a. To bail the water (out).**
>
> **1829   F. Marryat** Naval Officer II. i. 14   *One [man] to bail the water out.*

You will note that both examples are from the same writer. The confusion deepens with the earliest mention:

> 1627   J. Smith Sea Gram. vi. 27   To **baile** or cast out the water.

This leads to:

> **1. to bail out.**

> **a. intransitive. Originally U.S. Of a person: to make an emergency descent by parachute from an aeroplane.**
>
> 1925   Oakland (Calif.) Tribune 1 Sept. 2 b/3   *The..pilot who has to
> ‘**bail** out’ hurriedly from a crippled or burning plane.*
>
> 1939   F. D. Tredrey Pilot's Summer 28   *If you **bale** out and land
> in water..a smart rap will release the whole lot and you can swim
> free.*

And the extended sense of

> **b. intransitive. colloquial. To leave hurriedly; to escape an unpleasant situation or abandon a burdensome responsibility. Also with
> of or on.**
>
> 1941   R. Riskin Meet John Doe in Six Screenplays (1997) 623   *Boy
> Midget. Come on, Snooks—you better bail out. Girl Midget. Goodbye, Mr.
> Doe!*

And

> **c. intransitive. Originally and chiefly Surfing. To jump or dive off a surfboard in order to avoid injury when a fall seems imminent; to
> make a similar jump from a bicycle, skateboard, etc.**
>
> 1962   T. Masters Surfing made Easy 64   ***Bailing** out, getting off
> and away from the surfboard on purpose.*
>
> a1970   S. Afr. Surfer 1 ii. 27 in Stud. in Eng. (Univ. Cape Town)
> (1970) 1 32   *Some kook dropped in on my best wave. He pearled as I
> came through a hot section. I had to **bale** out.*

And finally we arrive at **bail** in the sense of to leave rather than stay; to desert; forsake [someone/something].

> **2. slang (originally North American)**.
> **a. intransitive. = sense 1b. Also with on.**
>
> 1977   G. F. R. Filosa Surfer's Almanac 181   *Bail,..to leave,
> depart, exit.*
>
> 1982   M. Pond Valley Girl's Guide to Life 51   *When you skip
> school.., it's cool to go, ‘like, I bailed, man.’ Or when you leave a
> party, you go, ‘Let's bail.’*

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467078/if-my-boat-is-sinking-should-i-bale-or-bail-the-water-out?noredirect=1&lq=1